# Translate child coordinates of ui to UI world position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a UI rendering in "screen space - camera; In this Ui i have a UI canvases for each side of the screen. These contain spawn points for items that are then launched into the screen space.

I used the UI to place them so they scale with the users screen as i can anchor them to the sides. Below you can see the middle box is the players screen and the boxes around it that contain the spawn points.

[image]

Here is a picture of my spawn points so u can see what order they are in.

[image]

Spawns in the top box have the same coordinates as the bottom box as their parents are differnt so when items go to spawn there, they just spawn in the bottom box. What i need is to translate these coordinate into their parents space or something.

I tried this which gave the same result:

```
waveFourSpawnPoints[0].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint(Vector3 position)` for converting from world space to screen space.

You will posibly need to convert from local to world space first with `Transform.TransformPoint` (as you are already doing), then from world to screen.

```
camera.WorldToScreenPoint(waveFourSpawnPoints[0].transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.zero))
```

EDIT:

If you want to convert from the local coordinates of an object to the local coordinates of other object (e.g. from the coordinates of a object to the coordinate of its parent), you can transform the point from the local coordinate of the frist object to world, then transform from world to the local of the second object with `Transform.InverseTransformPoint`.

```
second.transform.InverseTransformPoint(first.transform.TransformPoint(point))
```

Comment: That didnt work, i think its because it has a UI for a parent

Comment: Check the edit. What are the Component Types of the parent and child objects? DO they have  ´RectTransform´ instead of ´Transform´?

Comment: Sorry some other code was wrong, that did actually work now, thankyou :)